# Joomla session timeout with IE causes incorrect redirects

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I've got a Joomla 2.5.6 site that is experiencing problems with IE only. If a user logs into the site for registered content but then times out due to inactivity they get redirected to the login page...as expected.

The problem is that when they try to login in back they get a 403 error. If they enter the url manually (to some registered content) they actually do get logged in.

Even to add to that, they have several menus available and most work correctly however others just give a 403 error.

Clearing cache in IE resolves this issue. However if the user times out again then the whole cycle repeats. I should mention there are no problems in Firefox or Chrome.

Not sure what I can provide to help debug this? Any ideas?

Comment: Is it a fresh installation or is there installed components and/or plugins active?

Comment: @LukeWyatt There are installed components and other plugins that are active.

Comment: typical IE isn't it. If you have other extensions installed, it's most likely one of them causing the problem. Might be an idea to run some tests on a subdomain, installing each extensions one by one and finding the problem.

Comment: If it's IE and there are 3rd party extensions check for JS errors, if one of the extensions is providing "optimisation" through CSS & JS compression/combining then disable it and see if the problem persists.